# Finding Median of a Min Heap

Tags: algorithm, heap, median

If I already have a min heap built what is the fastest way I can find the median? Seems like it is redundant to use the 2 heap (max and min) solution.

Comment: What advantages does a min heap has when searching for a Median?

Comment: Faster than removing the minimum `n / 2` times? That will be `O(n log n)`, and pretty fast in practice.

Comment: Yes looking for something with O(n) time complexity

Comment: I am currently thinking the solution won't alter the heap

Comment: Why not use an O(n) algorithm that doesn't require a heap?

Comment: @jsho You can use any k-select algorithms where k is the median. This will satisfy all your requirements. No need for min heap tough...